# How to print Trac ticket report results in pdf format with form feed (new page) after each ticket?

Tags: pdf, report, trac

Usually it is not necessary to print out report results in Trac, but in this case I need a printout in PDF format with each ticket on a new page.

Steps:

1. Create a Trac report or use an existing one (Menu: View Tickets)
2. View Report
3. Print the result (CTRL-P)

This will print the Trac tickets in tabular format. I need this with form feed (new page) after each ticket.
Any ideas?

My Trac version is 1.0.11

Comment: Please add more information, especially your code.

Comment: Are you wanting each PDF page to contain just the one-line summary from the report?  Or the detailed information block from the top of each ticket's page?

Comment: The one-line summary is not enough, I need more details (like each ticket's page).  As first workaround I tried the [StickyTicketPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/StickyTicketPlugin) which generates a short configurable ticket overview with one or more tickets per PDF page.

Comment: If you can implement the page break in CSS, you can add [custom CSS to your site](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#SiteAppearance).

Comment: That is a promising aproach, thank you. I use already a project specific `./templates/site.html` to set the Change History button collapsed. I could include a custom `./htdocs/style.css`, but i'm afraid my CSS skills are too weak. Could you give me a hint which property I have to set, and to what value?